# How to add integer attribute option value in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, product-attribute, custom-options

I have used below code for add new attribute options in magento 2.

```
 if (!$optionId) {

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $attribute_id = $this->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getAttributeId();

            $languageValues[0] = $label;
            $languageValues[1] = $label;

            $attr = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute'); 
            $attr->load($attribute_id); 

            $option = []; 
            $option['value'][$languageValues[0]] = $languageValues; 
            $attr->addData(array('option' => $option));

            $attr->save();

            // Get the inserted ID. Should be returned from the installer, but it isn't.
            $optionId = $this->getOptionId($attributeCode, $label, true);
        }
```

But its work only when attribute option is alphabet when i am trying with numeric value its not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have find out solution for above problem.

```
public function createOrGetId($attributeCode, $label)
    {

        $optionId = $this->getOptionId($attributeCode, $label);

        if (!$optionId) {

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $attribute_id = $this->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getAttributeId();

            $languageValues[0] = $label;
            $languageValues[1] = $label;
            $languageValues[2] = $label;
            $languageValues[3] = $label;

            $attr = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute'); 
            $attr->load($attribute_id); 

            $option = array(); 
            $option['value'][$attributeCode] = $languageValues; 
            $attr->addData(array('option' => $option));

            $attr->save();

            // Get the inserted ID. Should be returned from the installer, but it isn't.
            $optionId = $this->getOptionId($attributeCode, $label, true);
        }

        return $optionId;
    }
```